# Uploading multiple files only one Ajax requests succeeds (Blueimp jQuery fileupload plugin)

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have spent hours on this but haven't been able find a solution. I am trying to upload multiple files in an ASP.Net web forms application using Blueimp jQuery plugin but Ajax request for only one file succeeds and rest return Aborted.

Override Add call in app.js:

```
add: function(e, data){
                var that = this;

                $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.add.call(that, e, data);

                $("#fu-start").on('click', function () {

                    if(typeof data.files[0].error == 'undefined'){
                        data.submit();
                    }

                    $(this).addClass('progress');
                });
            },
```

Files data is submitted on button submit:

```
'<a id="add_files" class="button" href="javascript:void(0)">',
                            '<i class="list-button lb-add"></i>',
                            '{{{cardstyle_buttons_addfiles}}}',
                            '<input type="file" multiple name="files[]" id="fileupload">',
                        '</a>',
                        '<a class="button btn btn-primary start disabled" id="fu-start" href="javascript:void(0)">',
                            '<i class="list-button lb-start-up"></i>',
                            '<span>Start upload</span>',
                        '</a>'
```

On the server side in generic handler (.ashx):

```
            var file = context.Request.Files[0];

            ProcessImage(context, file, statuses, merchantId, pType);
```

There is no issue with one file uploading. But when multiple files are selected, in FireBug, requests are sent equal to number of files selected but only one of them succeeds. rest of them are aborted as shown below.

[image]

Unsuccessful Request Header:

[image]

Successful Request Header:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you expect to handle multiple files in your for loop, as each file is being sent as a separate request according to your fire bug image. Surely the `context.Request.Files.Count` will always be 1?

Comment: Agree, but that didn't resolve the issue.